# Defining a new environment out of `restatable`

Tags: theorems, thmtools

I am preparing a manuscript for a conference that offers a class file and a package of macros. In the style file, they have

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
```

and similar lines, and in the macro package, they have

```
\newcommand{\thmvspace}{.4pc plus .2pc minus .1pc}
\newenvironment{theorem}{\vspace{-\lastskip}\par\addvspace{\thmvspace}\begin{thm}}{\end{thm}\par\addvspace{\thmvspace}}
```

Authors are supposed to use the environment `theorem` in their manuscript.  I am guessing that the macro in the package adjusts spaces before and after theorems, but I don't know how it exactly works.

Now, because I have proofs in the appendix,  I want to restate theorems there by using `thmtools` and `thm-restate`.  I end up loading these after the class file does `\newtheorem` , which is itself a problem.  Since the conference has authors prepare camera-ready PDF files and does not care about the LaTeX source, I need only produce something very close to what they intended.  So I thought I could declare a theorem-type environment `mythm` of my own and define an environment like the one in the package provided by the conference.  So my minimal (non-)working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}

\declaretheorem{mythm}
\newcommand{\thmvspace}{.4pc plus .2pc minus .1pc}
\newenvironment{theorem-restatable}[2][]{\vspace{-\lastskip}\par\addvspace{\thmvspace}\begin{restatable}[#1]{mythm}{#2}}{\end{mythm}\par\addvspace{\thmvspace}}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem-restatable}[Tarski]{tarski}
  Truth is undefinable.
\end{theorem-restatable}
\tarski*
\end{document}
```

But this produces the error:

```
File ended while scanning use of \thmt@collect@body.
```

This may be something related to fragile macros and lack of `\protect`, but I can't figure out what's wrong.  How can I define an environment like the one defined in the macro package but with `restatable`?

Comment: I bet the conference is AiML isn't it? I hate that class file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

First in `theorem-restatable`, you write `\begin{restatable}...` but `\end{mythm}`, so these are mismatched.

The problem which actually causes the error is that the parsing of the environment body by `restatable` is incompatible with writing `\begin{restatable}` in the begin-code of an environment. Similarly to `align`, you have to use `\restatable` and `\endrestatable` instead of `\begin{restatable}` and `\end{restatable}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}

\declaretheorem{mythm}
\newcommand{\thmvspace}{.4pc plus .2pc minus .1pc}
\newenvironment{theorem-restatable}[2][]{\vspace{-\lastskip}\par\addvspace{\thmvspace}\restatable[#1]{mythm}{#2}}{\endrestatable\par\addvspace{\thmvspace}}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem-restatable}[Tarski]{tarski}
  Truth is undefinable.
\end{theorem-restatable}
\tarski*
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the first stupid error...